# A different take on FirstOrDefault

Tags: c#, extension-methods

The IEnumerable extension method FirstOrDefault didn't exactly do as I wanted so I created FirstOrValue. Is this a good way to go about this or is there a better way?

```
public static T FirstOrValue<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate, T value)
{
    T first = source.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
    return Equals(first, default(T)) ? value : first;
}
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Your code is probably incorrect; you probably haven't considered all of the cases.

Of course, we cannot know if any code is correct or incorrect until we have a spec. So start by writing a one-line spec:

"`FirstOrValue<T>` takes a sequence of T, a predicate, and a value of T, and returns either the first item in the sequence that matches the predicate if there is one, or, if there is not, the stated value."

Does your attempt actually implement that spec?  Certainly not!  Test it:

```
int x = FirstOrValue<int>( new[] { -2, 0, 1 }, y=>y*y==y, -1);
```

this returns -1. The correct answer according to the spec is 0. The first item that matches the predicate is zero, so it should be returned.

A correct implementation of the spec would look like:

```
public static T FirstOrValue<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Func<T, bool> predicate, T value)
{
    if (sequence == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("sequence");
    if (predicate == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("predicate");
    foreach(T item in sequence)
        if (predicate(item)) return item;
    return value;
}
```

Always write a spec first, even if it's only a single sentence.

Comment: This should be part of the Framework! Or did I overlook that?

Answer (score 5):

`default(T)` will return `null` by default for reference types.

I would do this

```
public static T FirstOrValue<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate, T value)
{
    T first = source.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
    return first ?? value;
}
```

Comment: I'll just write it on a single line:
return source.FirstOrDefault(predicate) ?? value;

Comment: @zote: doing it daniels way makes it easier to attach a debugger and see what is going on

Comment: But this won't work as ?? can only be used on nullable types.

Comment: Also won't work if null is a valid element of your collection.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an overload, it's worth mentioning the version with no predicate.

```
public static T FirstOrValue<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, T value)
{
    if (sequence == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("sequence");
    foreach(T item in sequence) 
        return item; 
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Suppose the sequence has a million items in it and no Count property. You would enumerate *all* of them to determine that there are not *none* of them.  If you have a million pennies in a jar, and you wish to know if the jar is empty,do you count the pennies? This is a very, very bad technique that you are using here.  (It is also not clear to me why you are posting answers to a six-year-old question that has an accepted correct answer already, and are in fact not even answering the original question; perhaps there is some other way you could be adding more value to the site?)

Comment: I was looking for FirstOrValue and came across your lovely answer. I copied your code over and it occurred to me there's an overload. Pasted this here in case others went through the same thought process. Maybe you could suggest a better way to do this.

Comment: Well, since your proposed method is the same as the one I wrote except without a predicate, my suggestion would be to write the same method without a predicate:  `public static T FirstOrValue<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, T value) {
    if (sequence == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("sequence");
    foreach(T item in sequence)
      return item;
    return value;
}`

Answer (score -1):

Seems reasonable to me if you want to tweak the readability instead of using DefaultIfEmpty.

You could also create an override that uses a lambda if the creation of the default value is expensive, creating it only if necessary.

```
public static T FirstOrValue<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate, Func<T> getValue)
{
    T first = source.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
    return Equals(first, default(T)) ? getValue() : first;
}
```

Comment: Very nice, the addition of a lambda makes it even more useful.