# Return null for FirstOrDefault() on empty IEnumerable<int>?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Say I have the following snippet:

```
int? nullableId = GetNonNullableInts().FirstOrDefault();
```

Because `GetNonNullableInts()` returns integers, the `FirstOrDefault` will default to `0`.
Is there a way to make the `FirstOrDefault` on a list of integers return a `null` value when the list is empty?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
int? nullableId = GetNonNullableInts().Cast<int?>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Is there no way to define the Default from FirstOrDefault?
When the list does return a set of ints, casting them all for no real reason doesn't really look like a good idea to me.

Comment: Cast() does not cast them all - it only casts them as you enumerate. So this code will cast either zero or one ints - not much of a performance hit.

Comment: You cannot define the default value returned by FirstOrDefault - it returns either the first element from the enumerable, or if none exists, the result of `default(T)`.

Comment: You are correct, I was confused. Parsing one value is no biggy.

Comment: And if you want to implement FirstOrValue, here's an article on how to do it wrong vs how to do it right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708846/a-different-take-on-firstordefault

Comment: @BorisCallens When you want to give a specific "default" value, if you don't want to create your own extension method as in the link in the comment above, you might use `source.DefaultIfEmpty(yourValue).First()`. This is no good for changing types, like from `int` to `int?`, so it is not like in your question.

Comment: The issue with this is that, if the type that is returned by the fictional method `GetNonNullableInts` is changed, the cast will hide the type change compile-time error.

Answer (score 1):

`FirstOrDefault` depends on `T` from `IEnumerable<T>` to know what type to return, that's why you're receiving `int` instead `int?`.

So you'll need to cast your items to `int?` before return any value, just like [Matt said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825304/return-null-for-firstordefault-on-empty-ienumerableint/1825335#1825335)