# FirstOrDefault Behavior with Int and Int?

Tags: c#, linq

I just read a SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825304/return-null-for-firstordefault-on-empty-ienumerableint.) that explained that `FirstOrDefault()`'s return type will vary based on the value of the element being selected.

Example:

```
ICollection<String> list = new List<String>();
list.Add("bye");

int a = (from x in list where (x == "hi") select x.Length).FirstOrDefault();
```

In this example, `a` will be equal to 0 since the `int` default value is 0.

However, I can append `.Cast<int?>()` as per the already linked post in order to get `null` when the query returns 0 results.

```
int? a = (from x in list where ... x.Length).Cast<int?>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Why don't I get a compile-time error (or at least a warning) when, for my first example, I use a Nullable int (`int?`) rather than a regular `int`?

If I understand correctly, using a `int?` when performing my first query will **never** result in a value of `null`.

Comment: Your question is not clear, to me. What exact code compiles without warning where you expected an error/warning? It is correct that the defalt value for `int` is `0`, and that of `int?` is `null`.

Comment: Hi @JeppeStigNielsen - I was confused why the compiler, for the `int?` example above, would let me use the Nullable type even though `null` will never be returned. `dasblinkenlight` fully answered my question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Why don't I get a compile-time error (or at least a warning) when, for my first example, I use a Nullable `int` rather than a regular `int` then?
>   If I understand correctly, using a int? when performing my first query will never result in a value of `null`.

Your understanding is correct. However, the compiler does not interfere with your desire to declare variable `a` as nullable, because it is a "widening" conversion: even though the assignment from the LINQ query would never return a `null`, you may have other use for the same variable down below:

```
int? a = (from x in list where (x == "hi") select x.Length).FirstOrDefault();
// Do something with `a`, which will not be null
...
a = null;
if (someCondition) {
    a = someNotNullValue();
}
// Here, a may or may not be null
...
```

Comment: [aside] Wouldn't you argue against using the variable `a` in multiple spots since, as I recall from Code Complete and experience, increasing the span of a variable can hurt readability.

Comment: @Kevin I would be the first one to argue against re-using a variable, unless one reuses it for a closely related purpose. Compilers, however, should not be held responsible for enforcing best practices: they must obey what programmers tell them to do, letting programmers worry about such "unimportant" things as the readability of their own programs.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful words.

Comment: So if it doesn't not find the element what does it return? a `0` ?

Comment: @Zapnologica: Yes, it returns zero. int? and int will both return zero.